# Order and group by date in Mysql

Tags: mysql, subquery

Hi all and thanks in advance.
I have a small problem which can not resolve, I have this table, and I want to sort by date and group it (but I only show 1 row per idCAT)

```
| id | idcat | name |     date   |

| 1  | 3     | xx   | 2011-01-02 |

| 2  | 4     | xf   | 2011-01-02 |

| 3  | 3     | cd   | 2011-01-01 |

| 4  | 1     | cg   | 2011-01-04 |

| 5  | 4     | ce   | 2011-01-06 |
```

---

would like to stay that way, try in a way but I can not

```
| 2  | 4     | xf   | 2011-01-02 |

| 3  | 3     | cd   | 2011-01-01 |

| 4  | 1     | cg   | 2011-01-04 |
```

Order by ID

---

Thank's a one friend the work.

```
SELECT id, idcat, name, date FROM (SELECT * FROM data ORDER BY idcat, date ) m GROUP BY idcat
```

Comment: What logic are you using to get the desired results? `2011-01-01` isn't in the same row as any of `2, 4, xf` in the source data.

Comment: I do not understand that logic?

Comment: Sorry, is 2 | 4 | xf | 2011-01-02

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I can't test conveniently atm, but try this:

```
SELECT FIRST(id), idcat, FIRST(name), FIRST(date) AS d FROM myTable GROUP BY idcat ORDER BY d;
```

Note the use of the FIRST calls to pick the first row in the table with any particular idcat.

Comment: If you need more specific rows, like, say, the most recent in each idcat, you'll need to do a bitmore: SELECT FIRST(id), idcat, FIRST(name), FIRST(date) as d FROM (SELECT * FROM myTable ORDER BY date DESC) GROUP BY idcat ORDER BY d;  Change DESC to ASC for the oldest item per idcat.

Answer (score -1):

If you are trying to get groupings by the idcat, then sorted by date:

select id, idcat, name, date from myTable group by idcat order by date;

Comment: It does not work, I tried it, then ordered it brings, ideally before ordering it and then grouping

Comment: You should first sort dates according to the idcat and they choose the oldest and then package it so that only the oldest return for each idcat

Comment: Hmmm, much harder, I see your dilemma. If I understand you, you'd like to get a list of the oldest of each idcat, ordered by date.

Comment: How about "select id, idcat, name, date from myTable order by date descending group by idcat;"

Comment: Well as I have the table as such idcat 4, there are two rows of which would be sorted by date of 01/02/2011 idcat 4 and so on for the rest of idCAT (3.1)